# CDI @inject failed for @producer

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, cdi

My produced resource doesn't get injected though everything seems to be fine, 
`LoggerProducer.java`

```
import java.util.logging.Logger;

import javax.enterprise.inject.Produces;
import javax.enterprise.inject.spi.InjectionPoint;

 public class LoggerProducer {
        @Produces
        public Logger getLogger(InjectionPoint injectionPoint) {
            return Logger.getLogger(injectionPoint.getClass().getName());
        }
    }
```

`LoggerServiceImpl.java`

```
import java.util.logging.Logger;

import javax.enterprise.context.RequestScoped;
import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.inject.Named;

import org.bala.java.jee.cdi.producer.control.LoggerService;


@RequestScoped
@Named("LoggerService")
public class LoggerServiceImpl implements LoggerService {
    @Inject
    Logger logger;

        /*
         * (non-Javadoc)
         * @see org.bala.java.jee.cdi.producer.control.LoggerService#getLoggingClass()
         */
        @Override
        public String getLoggingClass() {
            try {
                System.out.println(logger.getName());
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return logger.getName();
        }
    }
```

Stack trace,

```
    2017-07-10T11:06:45.770+0530|Severe: Exception while loading the app
2017-07-10T11:06:45.770+0530|Severe: Undeployment failed for context /jee-showcase
2017-07-10T11:06:45.785+0530|Severe: Exception while loading the app : CDI deployment failure:WELD-001408: Unsatisfied dependencies for type Logger with qualifiers @Default
  at injection point [BackedAnnotatedField] @Inject org.bala.java.jee.cdi.producer.boundary.LoggerServiceImpl.logger
  at org.bala.java.jee.cdi.producer.boundary.LoggerServiceImpl.logger(LoggerServiceImpl.java:0)
org.jboss.weld.exceptions.DeploymentException: WELD-001408: Unsatisfied dependencies for type Logger with qualifiers @Default
  at injection point [BackedAnnotatedField] @Inject org.bala.java.jee.cdi.producer.boundary.LoggerServiceImpl.logger
  at org.bala.java.jee.cdi.producer.boundary.LoggerServiceImpl.logger(LoggerServiceImpl.java:0)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateInjectionPointForDeploymentProblems(Validator.java:355)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateInjectionPoint(Validator.java:277)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateGeneralBean(Validator.java:130)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateRIBean(Validator.java:151)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateBean(Validator.java:494)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateBeans(Validator.java:480)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateDeployment(Validator.java:455)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.WeldStartup.validateBeans(WeldStartup.java:454)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.WeldBootstrap.validateBeans(WeldBootstrap.java:90)
    at org.glassfish.weld.WeldDeployer.event(WeldDeployer.java:227)
    at org.glassfish.kernel.event.EventsImpl.send(EventsImpl.java:131)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.ApplicationInfo.load(ApplicationInfo.java:329)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:497)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:220)
    at org.glassfish.deployment.admin.DeployCommand.execute(DeployCommand.java:487)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:539)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:535)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:360)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:534)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$3.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:565)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$3.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:557)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:360)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:556)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1464)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.access$1300(CommandRunnerImpl.java:109)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1846)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1722)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.doCommand(AdminAdapter.java:534)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.onMissingResource(AdminAdapter.java:224)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.StaticHttpHandlerBase.service(StaticHttpHandlerBase.java:189)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:466)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:169)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:206)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:180)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:235)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:284)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:201)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:133)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:526)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:591)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:571)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

`Beans.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee 
       http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/beans_1_1.xsd"
       bean-discovery-mode="all">
</beans>
```

Environment used :

```
 Eclipse Version: Kepler Service Release 2
 Java Version: jdk 7 
 Payara: payara41
```

Comment: Shot in the dark: try to make the producer method public (which is the only difference I can spot to the code I normally write.)

Comment: @mtj no luck, Still the same error is thrown

Comment: thanks, @fg78nc, worked great, after adding `@applicationscoped`  over `LoggerProducer`

Comment: You are welcome, I will add answer, if you don't mind

Comment: sure, waiting to see your answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LoggerProducer is not managed bean, you need to annotate it with appropriate scope annotation.